# Motherboard for a Dual Quad Core i7 processor?

Tags: computer-building, intel-core-i7

I was wondering if there are motherboards that support two i7 Quad core processors (total 8 core support) with 32GB RAM. I was looking for it on the Dell website but could not find it. Any suggestions on how these systems are built?

Comment: Shopping advice is Off Topic on Super User. [Why it is so.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: I'd say that they aren't. I could be wrong, but I think that you'd need Xeons for dual processor system.

Comment: You totally need Xeon chips. Try http://newegg.com

Comment: If you are shopping, then this is off topic for Super User.  As for asking about dual i7's on one board, if you are going to stay with intel chips, you will need their Xeon line of chips to accomplish that.  Intel designed it purposely that way.  The i7 platform only support one physical CPU.

Comment: Voted for re-open: He's not asking for boards to buy, he's asking if they exist and what technologies he should be looking for.

Comment: Some related questions: http://superuser.com/questions/122914/intel-i7-vs-xeon-quad-core-processor , http://superuser.com/questions/149409/how-does-xeon-differ-from-regular-processors , trying to find this other question, I remember this being asked before. If I can't find the other question, then we will need to re-write this into a better question.

Comment: This question was asking a similar thing, but with the i5 series. The both have similar answers. http://superuser.com/questions/195469/dual-socket-core-i5-motherboards  If you notice on the right hand side of the page, you will see all these questions I am linking to in the "Linked" section.

Comment: True, so I guess it's more of a Dupe than a Shopping question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no boards that (officially) support i7 in a dual CPU setup.  You need DP-capable Xeons (not UP) to do SMP with more than one physical CPU.  These days I think all the Xeons (55xx+) support QuickPath, and if they support QuickPath then they should work in a configuration with more than one physical CPU.

An example Xeon 5500/5600 series workstation board from Intel is the "[Intel® Workstation Board S5520SCR](http://serverconfigurator.intel.com/details.aspx?id=3825)"

HTH.