# How do Xeon processors differ from regular processors in 2022?

Tags: cpu, computer-architecture, xeon

What's the difference between a Xeon processor and a regular processor? Of course Xeon processors are meant for server use. But that's just the intention, it doesn't tell anything about the actual differences inside.

I have read this question from 14 years ago: [How do Xeon processors differ from regular processors?](https://superuser.com/questions/149409/how-do-xeon-processors-differ-from-regular-processors) It says that Xeon processors operate on different motherboards. Probably because you can have more than one in a single housing, according to that post. Also they support ECC RAM and might have some other extra features. But the cores themselves are much the same. As far as I'm aware that's the case for many different processor models/variants from the same generation.

Also Xeon processors allegedly support more cores, more cache, more RAM, more PCIe lanes and more instruction set extensions.

But if you actually look into the data sheet of a Ryzen 9 7950X, it has a lot of cores, cache and supported RAM, too. It has the same instruction set extensions, higher clock speed but not as many PCIe lanes. However, it costs 700€ and not 2000-5000€.

So how does this price come about if the actual differences are that small?

Comment: There is little difference between a Intel Core processor and an Intel Xeon processor, both are built upon the same x86 architecture, product segmentation surrounding product features, likely are the only differences. The answer from 14 years ago still applies in my opinion. What do AMD processors have to do with Intel's Core processors? You can't compare Xeon (Enterprise) to Ryzen (consumer) they are entirely different classes of processors.

Comment: I know Ryzen is not manufactured in the exact same way as Intel processors are. It was just meant as a example for comparing the performance of an enterprise CPU to a modern consumer CPU (both x86). Picking an Intel Core processor from the same generation would be more fitting.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's interesting but still I wonder how this justifies the tremendous price difference?

Comment: It simply comes down to market product segmentation. Intel does not have to "justify" the price difference, Enterprise (Corporations) are able to afford a higher price point while consumers (individuals buying OEM machines) are likely unwilling to purchase those more expensive products.  The evidence to that fact is you can't get a laptop with a Xeon processor at Best Buy or Walmart, if there was a market for it, companies (Dell, HP, etc) would manufacture the product.

Comment: I see. I guess it's just down to what people are willing to pay. You're right, corporations probably can and will pay more than normal people. Thanks for your response.